# mysql row comparison cursor vs joins

Tags: mysql, cursor, comparison, row

I need to compare all rows in a table and need to do some calculation on every comparison.

For eg:
I have 3 users.I need to compare a->b and give some marks to b and insert this in another table and then a->c do the calculation and store in the above same table and then need to compare b->c and do the calculation and insert the calculated value to a table.then c->a,c->b,-a do same as above.

How can we do these kind of comparison ? should I Use cursor ? any other simple ways ?

I am able to write a simple join query like this but no idea how to do calculation and insert this into another table.

**id,userid,lat,lng is the table structure.** I need to return lat and lng in each comparison ( I mean When I do a user to user) and then assign a value to second user as described above.id is pk and userid will be a non repeat value and its unique .Basically while returning lat and lng I need to check the distance calculation for each users based on one to one comparison and giving marks based on the distance then storing these marks in another table based on the user id.

**`Select * from table t1 join table t2 on t1.userid!=t2.userid`**

Comment: Could you add your existing table structure, some example data and the desired result? The question is a bit hard to answer other than "in general".

Comment: id,userid,lat,lng is the table structure.I need to return lat and lng in each comparison ( I mean When I do a user to user) and then assign a value to second user as described above.id is pk and userid will be a non repeat value and its unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created some thing like and works

```
INSERT INTO summary (user_id1, user_id2, distance, points)
SELECT a1.userid, a2.userid, 
    GetDistances(a1.lat,a1.lng,a2.lat,a2.lng) as distance,
GetDistance(a1.lat,a1.lng,a2.lat,a2.lng) as points FROM location a1 JOIN location a2 ON a1.userid <> a2.userid
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    distance=VALUES(distance),
    points=points+values(points);
```

For points

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP   FUNCTION  IF EXISTS `GetDistance`$$ 

CREATE   FUNCTION  `GetDistance`( 
 lat1  numeric (9,6), 
 lon1  numeric (9,6), 
 lat2  numeric (9,6), 
 lon2  numeric (9,6) 
)  RETURNS   decimal (10,5) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE  x  decimal (20,10); 
  DECLARE  pi  decimal (21,20);
  DECLARE final decimal (10,5);
DECLARE newvalue decimal (10,5);  
  SET  pi = 3.14159265358979323846; 
  SET  x = sin( lat1 * pi/180 ) * sin( lat2 * pi/180  ) + cos( 
 lat1 *pi/180 ) * cos( lat2 * pi/180 ) * cos(  abs( (lon2 * pi/180) - 
 (lon1 *pi/180) ) ); 
  SET  x = atan( ( sqrt( 1- power( x, 2 ) ) ) / x ); 
  SET final =  ( 1.852 * 60.0 * ((x/pi)*180) ) / 1.609344;

case WHEN final < 247 THEN  
SET newvalue = 2;
WHEN final > 600 THEN
SET newvalue = 1; 
else SET newvalue = 0;
END CASE;
RETURN newvalue;
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

For distance

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP   FUNCTION  IF EXISTS `GetDistances`$$ 

CREATE   FUNCTION  `GetDistances`( 
 lat1  numeric (9,6), 
 lon1  numeric (9,6), 
 lat2  numeric (9,6), 
 lon2  numeric (9,6) 
)  RETURNS   decimal (10,5) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE  x  decimal (20,10); 
  DECLARE  pi  decimal (21,20);
  SET  pi = 3.14159265358979323846; 
  SET  x = sin( lat1 * pi/180 ) * sin( lat2 * pi/180  ) + cos( 
 lat1 *pi/180 ) * cos( lat2 * pi/180 ) * cos(  abs( (lon2 * pi/180) - 
 (lon1 *pi/180) ) ); 
  SET  x = atan( ( sqrt( 1- power( x, 2 ) ) ) / x ); 
 RETURN ( 1.852 * 60.0 * ((x/pi)*180) ) / 1.609344;
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: But no idea the use of  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    distance=VALUES(distance),
    points=points+values(points);

Answer (score 0):

```
Distance formula
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP   FUNCTION  IF EXISTS `GetDistance`$$ 

CREATE   FUNCTION  `GetDistance`( 
 lat1  numeric (9,6), 
 lon1  numeric (9,6), 
 lat2  numeric (9,6), 
 lon2  numeric (9,6) 
)  RETURNS   decimal (10,5) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE  x  decimal (20,10); 
  DECLARE  pi  decimal (21,20); 
  SET  pi = 3.14159265358979323846; 
  SET  x = sin( lat1 * pi/180 ) * sin( lat2 * pi/180  ) + cos( 
 lat1 *pi/180 ) * cos( lat2 * pi/180 ) * cos(  abs ( (lon2 * pi/180) - 
 (lon1 *pi/180) ) ); 
  SET  x = atan( ( sqrt( 1- power( x, 2 ) ) ) / x ); 
  RETURN  ( 1.852 * 60.0 * ((x/pi)*180) ) / 1.609344; 
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

I need to apply following points based on the distance

```
30 miles or less = 2 points
    30 - 50 = 1 points
    50 and up = 0 points
```